# How to randomize images from albums

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an image gallery. On the index file I want to show the albums with the images, see; http://www.robcnossen.nl/

I want to randomize the images that are inside these albums but I get all sorts of errors like:

> warning: rand() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in.

My code is;

```
foreach ($albums as $album) {
?><div><h2><?php
echo'<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'],'">',$album['name'], '</a>';?>       </h2><?php       
    echo'<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album["id"],'"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $album["id"], '/', $album["imagename"],'" title="" /></a>';
    ?></div><?php
}
```

The `$album["imagename"]` are the images inside the albums and I want to randomize this part. I tried for example:

```
rand($album["imagename"], 0)
```

but that gives an error.

I also tried shuffle;

```
foreach ($albums as $album) {
shuffle($album["imagename"]);
?><div><h2><?php
echo'<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'],'">',$album['name'], '</a>';?></h2><?php      
    echo'<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album["id"],'"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $album["id"], '/', $album["imagename"],'" title="" /></a>';
    ?></div><?php
}
```

But also there I get only errors.

Can anybody help me with this?

`var_dump($albums);`
 gives

```
array(2) {
   [0]=> array(8) { 
      ["id"]=> string(1) "8" 
      ["timestamp"]=> string(10) "1373890251" 
      ["name"]=> string(7) "Holland" 
      ["description"]=> string(19) "Fantastische foto's" 
      ["count"]=> string(1) "2" 
      ["imagename"]=> string(38) "KONICA MINOLTA DIGITAL CAMERA_428.jpeg" 
      ["image"]=> string(2) "63" 
      ["ext"]=> string(0) ""
   } 
   [1]=> array(8) { 
      ["id"]=> string(1) "9" 
      ["timestamp"]=> string(10) "1376914749" 
      ["name"]=> string(6) "Belgie" 
      ["description"]=> string(11) "Mooi Belgie" 
      ["count"]=> string(1) "2" 
      ["imagename"]=> string(12) "PICT0170.JPG" 
      ["image"]=> string(2) "66" 
      ["ext"]=> string(0) "" 
   }
  }
```

as result.

Comment: http://php.net/shuffle

Comment: And apply shuffle to the array not to a single value of that array.

Comment: @Robske: We expect users having a problem with a specific PHP function to read about that function in the manual and explain then why they think their code should work. "Not working" is not a question. And that you tried multiple things is fine and normally expected.

Comment: What is `$albums` btw? Please add a plain-text `var_export($albums);` and `var_dump($albums);` to your question.

Comment: I looked first on php.net/shuffle and other sites about rand() and shuffle, that is why I thought that I was doing the right thing with shuffle, but the problem is that $album["imagename"] is not seen as an array but it is in the foreach loop. I already did try all the solutions given here but all gives errors and I don't know why...

Comment: @ the edit. Can you put it as code? The last piece

Answer (score 0):

`shuffle` should work for you, but not if you put it *inside* the foreach loop, like your example code.  You need to shuffle *before* you start the loop.  Also, `shuffle` needs to be called with the array itself, not an item of the array:

```
shuffle($albums);
foreach ($albums as $album) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is not `$album` variable out of foreach block! Maybe you mean `$albums`?!

Comment: That is shuffle the albums, but I want to shuffle the images that is inside the albums.

Answer (score -1):

you should shuffle array out side the loop

```
<?php
 shuffle($albums);
 foreach ($albums as $album) 
 {
  ?><div><h2>
 <?php
  echo'<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'],'">',$album['name'], '</a>';
  ?>
  </h2>
  <?php      
      echo'<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album["id"],'"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $album["id"], '/', $album["imagename"],'" title="" /></a>';
  ?>
  </div>
  <?php
 }
```

Comment: How is this solving his problem?

Comment: @loko i forgot to correct the first line of code i.e.shuffle($albums);